# Good example of early and simple orbital mechanics?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, history

I am doing a talk on Katherine Johnson at my school *extremely soon* and I was wondering if you could give **a relatively quick example of a simplified calculation** in any kind of orbital mechanics relevant to her work. I have access to her original papers but it would be nicer to have some kind of **"toy example"** to illustrate to people who understand matrices, complex numbers etc. some idea of her work and what she might have "computed" in her job.

Comment: Analytical geometry was her specialty, but she also solved some things numerically.  In [her first scientific publication, Appendix B](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19980227091.pdf) appendix she has an illustrative example solving for burnout azimuthal angle iteratively.